# App behaves differently since new Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

i built an app that continues to work (listen to mic input) after screen is locked.

i use "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord"

the app was received in the appstore and works perfectly.

i recently downloaded the new Xcode (ver 4.2 build 4C199) for snow leopard.

i am now working on an update and noticed that it doesn't continue to work once the screen is locked,

i reverted to the exact same code that is in the appstore and if i run it from the Xcode (on device or simulator)

it behaves differently and doesn't work once the auto screen lock kicks in!

i don't know how to resolve this

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: no, it works as always, until the lock screen kicks in, if i slide to unlock it resumes fine. it also works fine when silence switch is activated (as it always did)

Comment: There should be nothing to do with what Xcode your using to cause a problem like this. Is there a different version of iOS is on your device when it does work and when it doesn't work?

Comment: no, i have ver 5.0.1 and the app store version works great, i don't know if it's the Xcode but thats the only thing that changed! maybe there is some parameter that i compile with that is different? what param could cause this?

Comment: anyone? i opened a bug report with apple ages ago, still no help

Comment: Different versions of XCode CAN cause your app to behave differently if you update your project settings. This can update your default compiler and other compiler flags. I've experienced this myself once with an app that was using three20 framework (urgh) and the different compilation flags altered the apps behaviour due to some floating point thingy or another...I forget the specifics, but it happened.